# how to generate and save unique value for customer attribute in magento

Tags: customer, eav

I have created custom attribute "CustomerAccount".Customer does not have access to this field .When new customer account is created CustomerAccount field should get random unique value and should get save in customer module.

Comment: And what do you want to do with that value? Why can't you use one of the other unique values?

Comment: I have created custom attribute successfully.We can enter the value from frontend also from backend and it also saves in database.But I don't want to save it from front end when the registration form is submitted unique , random CustomerAccount value should also get saved .I am using this CustomerAccount value for further validations.Using this customer account value i am allocating shops to that particular customer.I am not using email field because our customer does not provide us email value we generate email id using CustomerAccount value for eg:CustomerAccount@gmail.com

Comment: Most easy way is to use customer id or md5(customer id) or time(). If you want another format you should create some logic to generate unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension for creating customer attributes.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-manager-5092.html

and if you don't want to show them on front end you can modify saveAction() function of its indexcontroller.php where it decided where to show attributes. It can work with magento 1.7 CE